# Next() method does not continue iteration when called directly from the function in which it was created

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I created a function squared() with a next() method. The function has a start value of n = 0. The next method is expected to return a value and false if n is <= 5. It should continue to repeat this process each time i call next.
The problem i encountered is dat, when i call squared().next() directly in the console, it only continues to feed me the first return value. Meaning it still counts from 0 each time i call it.

But when i set the function squared to an object like this:
squaredIterator = squared();
Then i call it dis way:
squaredIterator.next();
It works perfectly and continues to iterate until n > 5.

What i dnt understand is why it only works well wen i call it from an object. Is it dat objects have a special memory where dey keep the last value of n???

```
function squared() {
      let n = 0;
      
      return {
       next() { 
         n++;
            
      if(n <= 5) {
    return {                                
         value: n * n,
         done: false
     };
    }
    return {
     value: undefined, 
     done: true
    }
  }
  };
}

console.log(squared().next());
console.log(squared().next());
// value: 1, done: false
// value: 1, done: false
let squaredIterator = squared();

console.log(squaredIterator.next());
// value: 1, done: false
console.log(squaredIterator.next();
// value: 1, done: true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `square()` it creates a new closure and returns a new object containing `next` which has that closure as its context.

Each time you call `square()` it'll create a new closure and object. But when you bind it to a variable `let squaredIterator = squared()`, you now have a reference to the returned object.

Then you can call `next()` from the same returned object, from within the same closure that was created when you bound the object in the beginning.

Consider this example:

```js
function Dog(name) {
  return {
    speak() { console.log(`Hi I'm ${name}`) }
  }
}

const rocky = Dog('Rocky')
const obie = Dog('Obie')

rocky.speak()
obie.speak()

Dog('Jericho').speak()
Dog('Silvester').speak()
```

Each time we call `Dog(exampleName)` we create a new closure where the variable `name = exampleName`. So the only way we can save and interact with that closure, is by creating a reference to it, AKA binding it to a variable.